# Rest reponse for empty field

Tags: rest, response

If I am querying RestResponse using below query:

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Name, AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE LastName = :req.params.get('name')];
```

For any account with an empty `AccountNumber`, the response will look like this :

```
  {  
    "attributes":{  
      "type":"Account",
      "url":"/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/0018E00000fffE7CCC"
    },
    "Name":"SMT TEST",
                               // No AccountNumber Here
    "Id":"0018E00000fffE7CCC"
  },
  {  
    "attributes":{  
      "type":"Account",
      "url":"/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/0018E00000Z0qqqAAA"
    },
    "Name":"SMTH TEST",
    "AccountNumber":"01234567",
    "Id":"0018E00000Z0qqqAAA"
  }
```

Is there any way to format with an empty string instead : `"AccountNumber":""` ?

Comment: can you please add more details, why you want such format? this looks like an x-y problem.

Comment: It's just a requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to get an empty string unless you write some code to make it so. Salesforce does not store empty strings in the database, only `null`; when you query a record with a Text field that does not contain data, `null` is what you get back.

When you serialize an object to JSON, which appears to be what you're doing, a queried sObject's fields that are `null` are omitted from the resultant JSON.

```
System.debug(JSON.serialize([SELECT AccountNumber FROM Account LIMIT 1]));
```

results in seeing no `AccountNumber` entry at all

> 08:17:15:006 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/0011R00001ypMKsQAM"},"Id":"0011R00001ypMKsQAM","RecordTypeId":"01236000000STbiAAG"}

If you explicitly set the `AccountNumber` to `null` or `''`, you will get a `null` or `''` entry in generated JSON:

```
List<Account> acts = [SELECT AccountNumber FROM Account LIMIT 1];

for (Account a : acts) {
    a.AccountNumber = '';
}

System.debug(JSON.serialize(acts));
```

> 08:25:03:007 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|[{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/0011R00001ypMKsQAM"},"Id":"0011R00001ypMKsQAM","RecordTypeId":"01236000000STbiAAG","AccountNumber":""}]

I think this requirement is a mistake, but if you absolutely must, that's going to be the way to go.

Comment: I though so, thanks for the answer